# How to create relationship between elements in collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There are set of nodes `User` and query returns a collection (e.g. two nodes `Mary` and `Mario` ).

```
match (u:User)
where u.name =~ 'M.*'
return u
```

How do I go about creating a relationship among themselves.  I don't know if this is possible. I am not doing anything particular, it's just a learning exercise.

```
match (u:User)
where u.name =~ 'M.*'
foreach ( n in nodes(u) | create (n)-[:knows]-> (n+1)) #=> I am stuck here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just match user twice and then use these pairs or use a range function within the foreach.

See this blog post: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/quickly-create-a-100k-neo4j-graph-data-model-with-cypher-only/

```
foreach (name in ["Martin", "Max","Marius"] | create (:User {name:name}))


MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.name =~ 'M.*'
WITH collect(u) as users
foreach ( i in range(1,length(users)-1) | 
  foreach (u1 in [users[i-1]] | foreach ( u2 in [users[i]] |  
    create (u1)-[:knows]-> (u2) ))
)
```

See this graph-gist, on how it works: http://gist.neo4j.org/?b01ae5a9a863e126c116

Comment: Are there any plans for English version of your book `Neo4j 2.0`. Tried German version with google translate but didn't work quite well.